# Hide column in excel by date YYYY MM for the rest of this year plus three more

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm trying to hide columns in excel with vba.

So far This is what I have it will hide after 36 months but I was just told that it needed to do the rest of the forecasted year plus three years then hide all months in year 4 and 5 except for December.

I added a picture of the spreadsheet all cells except for the input, cells C10 thru BJ12 and row 6, come from the second page of the workbook. In row 6 I was trying to take the year from row 9 and use it that way, It can be hard coded in but it must be dynamic because the startyear changes from the second page depending on the scenario and job selected.

```
'Hide all months except for December after 36 months
With Range("AM:BJ")
    .EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        For Each cell In Range("AM7:BJ7" & ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)
            Select Case cell.Value
            Case Is = "CurrentYear"
            Case Is = "12"
            cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End Select
    Next cell
End With
```

[image: image of what the spreadsheet looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! The code should keep all columns unhidden until 3 years after the starting year. Then it should hide all columns except the December months.

```
'Grab Starting Info
StartingAddress = "C9" 'Set this to first date location
StartingYear = Left(Range(StartingAddress).Value, 4) 'Grab first four characters as starting year

'Loop through all dates and determine which to hide/unhide
For i = 0 To Application.Columns.Count - 2
    If Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value = vbNullString Then
        Exit For 'Saves time because it doesn't go through entire loop but can if needed
    Else
        'Hides column if year is 3 years greater than the starting year and the month is not Dec.
        If CInt(Left(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 4)) > (3 + StartingYear) And Right(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 2) <> "12" Then
            Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Just in case columns from previous run are hidden
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Example: (Starting Date = 2015 10) The code will keep all columns unhidden until 2019 where it will then keep only the December months. If you wanted it to start hiding at 2018  then change

```
If CInt(Left(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 4)) > (3 + StartingYear) And Right(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 2) <> "12" Then
```

To

```
If CInt(Left(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 4)) >= (3 + StartingYear) And Right(Range(StartingAddress).Offset(0, i).Value, 2) <> "12" Then
```